# Locating point along line at specified distance from beginning of line and at given offset (buffer) from line either left or right using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, geometry-generator

In QGIS version 3.34.2, given a line, how do I locate a point at a given distance from the beginning of the line but also at a given offset (buffer) from the line?

I could use either available plugins, or "geometry by expression".

Let's say I have a polyline shape file name Line 1 that is 1000 m long.  I would like to create a point at 500 m from the beginning of the polyline but located 20 m to the left of the polyline at 90 deg.

I created a function for your expression. It works well.

Could you recommend a manual that lists the commands?

I have another request.

How about instead of manually typing the station, the offset, and the rotation; to get these values from a table with field-1 for point number, field-2 for the station, field-3 for the offset, and field-4 for the rotation?

Comment: I think your question would benefit from the inclusion of a picture.  What have you tried/researched?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: For help of QGIS expression functions, I added links, see edited answer. And yes, you can replace the functions with fieldnames to use the values saved there - simply insert the fieldname if they are on the same layer. If they are on another layer, it's a bit more difficult. So for this, it's important to know the exact use case and settings. You should post a separate question for that (you might make a link to this post here for context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Geometry Generator or Geometry by Expression with the expression below. To get a point on the other side of the line, change the number on line 6 to negative value (here: -25 instead of 25).

*Black: initial line; red point: your result, created with the expression from below; for visualization purpose only: yellow part of the line, distance of 500 m from line's start point; blue dot: point at 500 m from line start; red line: distance of 25 m perpendicular to the line:*
[image]

A detailed help with description of all QGIS expression functions and how to use each can be found in the help panel in the [QGIS expression string builder](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html#the-interface) on the right side (expand the groups, click on a function name and see the help in the right panel of the window) or in the [online help: List of functions](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_contains).

```
with_variable(
    'point',
    end_point (line_substring ($geometry, 0, 500)),  -- distance on the line from start point
    project(
        @point, 
        25,  -- distance perpendicular from line 
        radians(
            90 + line_interpolate_angle( 
                $geometry,
                line_locate_point( 
                    $geometry, 
                    @point
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```